# Importing marker dataset vs adding markers to map on the fly

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-marker

On my map users will be saving coordinates in an external database, which will show up as markers on the map. I was wondering if it would make more sense to keep the data 100% in an external database and just pull the data for those markers on the fly, or to import the data into a dataset and then tileset? The thing is, the data will be added over time, so I would need to continually add new points into the tileset.

Is it faster when data is kept in the data/tileset vs pulled from another server? Are there size limitations in pulling external data vs importing to data/tileset?

Answer (score 0):

What you're really asking is the difference between bulk loading a whole dataset as GeoJSON (or perhaps GeoBuf) and loading it via vector tiles.

As a basic rule of thumb, if the size of your data in GeoJSON is under 5MB, save yourself the complexity of vector tiles and just do that.

If it's over say 20MB you really have to use vector tiles. In the middle? Up to you.